# Vector space where $x+y=x$ and $y$ is not zero vector.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-fields, axioms

Suppose $V$ is a vector space and $x, y ∈ V$ with $x + y = x$. Is it true that $y$ must be the zero vector $0$ of $V$ ?
Is there a specific example of a vector space $V$ and two such vectors $x, y ∈ V$
with $yz ≠  0$ but $x + y = x$?

Is there any situation where $y$ is not $0$?

This was briefly mentioned in class and it was hinted that it is possible and I've thinking about it for a while but I can't come up with a specific example?

Does it count if $x = (1,1,1), y = (1,1,1)$, so $x+y = (2,2,2)$, where $(2,2,2) = (1,1,1)$ since its just a linear combination of $x$? I feel this example is weak and that $(2,2,2) = (1,1,1)$ is not an equality.

I've also been trying to think about vector spaces that are not in $R$ or some weird ones where there are only a couple elements in $V$.

Any thoughts on this? I've been stuck thinking about this for a while.

Here's a proof I did to prove $y=0$, but I don't know if it's weak.
Let $x,yEV$ where $x+y=x$. So, the $i-th$ components are $x_i, y_i$. If $x_i+y_i=x_i$ then, by adding the additive inverse of $x_i$, we get $x_i+y_i+(-x_i)=x_i+(-x_i)$, so  $y_i=0$. Thus, $y=0$.

Comment: $y=x-x=0$ so yes.

Comment: i think you can prove $y$ must be zero, using only the axioms of an arbitrary vector space. Try it!

Comment: $(V,+)$ is a group, so $y=0.$ Not clear what you mean by $yz\neq0.$

Comment: $(2,2,2)\neq (1,1,1).$ When you treat linear changes to a vector as “the same” you are no longer talking about vectors.

Comment: I can prove that $y=0$, but I'm looking for any possible example to disprove it. I also feel like I need a very rigorous proof for this.

Comment: There are finite fields, and finite vector spaces over finite fields. The only finite vector space over an infinite field $F$ is $\{0\}.$ Other vector spaces have a cardinality (size) at least as big as the cardinality of $F.$

Comment: A rigorous proof requires a rigorous definition of what a vector space is. There are a few possible definitions of vector space, all equivalent, but which definition you use affects how you prove it. @eddie

Comment: If you have a valid proof that something is true, searching for any possible example that it is false is going to be a long, fruitless search.

Comment: But at heart, all of the definitions of a vector space includes that $(V,+,0)$ is an abelian group. All groups have a cancellation property. For additive groups, this mean if $a+x=a+y$ then $x=y.$ Here you have $x+y=x+0$ so $y=0.$ Proving the cancellation property is not hard.

Comment: I wrote my proof at the bottom, did I use the $i-th$ components correctly?

Comment: That assumes a vector has components. There is no reason to define vectors in terms of components.

Answer (score -1):

Since $x+y=x$, we have $(-x)+x+y=(-x)+x=0$ so that $y=0$.